# Phase correction in FTIR (Fourier Transform Infrared Spectroscopy)

Tags: fourier-transform, spectroscopy

I am reading the book 'Fourier Transform Infrared Spectrometry' and there is a procedure in the data processing called 'Phase correction', which confuses me.

The True spectrum **$B(\tilde \nu)$** confuses me. The book tells the true spectrum is real-valued, but then where the phase of the frequency is contained?

[image]
[image: Phase Correction]

I found the [procedure online](https://www.essentialftir.com/fftTutorial.html) and I am not sure the sub step a in step No.4, which says 'a value of 1 at 2 times the ZPD location, and ramping back down to 0 at the right side.' Should it be 2 times the ZPD location of the complete interferogram or 2 times the ZPD location of the symmetric interferogram used for phase correction?